# Naked Call become short seller

Tags: stocks

Thanks for the low interest rate for years, it forcing me to do trading.
I have been doing option trading for 1.5 years.
I usually do selling covered put and covered call.
The first year got profit then the last few months get wiped out, ended lost for 2022 Tax season.
This year I have been trying different strategy which is safer but less profit.
Lastweek, I tried a credit spread.
I sell to open call AMD @ $81 2 contracts.
I buy to open call AMD @ $82 2 contracts.
And on Friday AMD was $81.52. I did not close the options because I want to know what happen if I don't close them.
On Saturday I got msg The $82 call was expired and the $81 was assigned.
I thought my broker will close the $81 and debit 200x$0.52 from my account.
Then something bizzare (for me) happened.
I have -200 AMD in my account!
Never have that before.
So basically I am become a short seller :)
I tried to "Buy to cover" on Monday and it was not success.
Then I set up a Buy order during after hour 100 AMD share for $80.80
Then today I set up "Buy to cover" 100 shares for $80.90
Then the price went down to $80.78
Now I ended up with:
100 AMD Stocks and -100 AMD Stocks.
And it says "Short vs Box" I goggle it And understand it.
My question is:
When we become a short seller, In my case I have -200 AMD shares for Sat,Sun,Mon (3 days) do I have to pay interest on it?
How can I cover the short 100 with 100 I just bought?
What should I do? No button to click.
Will my broker cover it automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For the most part, options that expire in-the-money (ITM) are automatically exercised by the OCC.  Since your short $81 call was ITM, you were assigned and you ended up with a short position in the stock.  Your long $82 call was OTM at expiration so it expired worthless.

You pay a borrow fee for every day that you are short a security.  It varies from next to nothing to 100s of percent.  For AMD, my broker is charging 0.25% (per year) today.  It accrues daily.

If the stock/ETF pays a dividend and you are short on the ex-dividend date, you pay the dividend to the lender of your shares.

When you buy shares to cover the short position, your broker should automatically net out the positions.